# how to share image to email and twitter in Flutter

Tags: flutter, email, twitter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16zpD.png)

Hello Seniors, I want to share image on clicking button to email and in twitter in flutter, I did
for empty email but i want to share the image in the mail and same for twitter.
Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far, and what code do you have? What is not working for you? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: void _sendEmail() {
    final Uri emailLaunchUri = Uri(
      scheme: 'mailto',
      path: 'Hello@hotlyme.app',
      queryParameters: {
        'subject': '',
        'body':
            '\n\n\n\n\nDevice:${_deviceData['product']}\nOSversion:${_deviceData['version.release']}'
      },
    );
    launchUrl(emailLaunchUri);
  } 

This is the code i used for email but i want to share the image in that email i selected

Answer (score 0):

you can use social_share package, link is
https://pub.dev/packages/social_share

Comment: This only works for Twitter I also need for email

Answer (score 0):

try this package flutter_share_me  here the link

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me

Answer (score 0):

You can use share_plus package.it used to share content across different platforms

```
await Share.shareFiles(
      imagePaths,
      text: text,
      subject: subject,
      sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);l̥
```